# How can I get this ruby code with sequel to work in sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel

I am trying to only allow a person to see the page if their name is in the database. I figured the best way to go about it was to loop through all of the entries and check if it matches, if it does then display it and stop looping. I keep getting a blank page, any help?

```
get '/' do
  user  = "john"
  num = DB[:users].all

  for person in num  do
    if person[:name].to_s == user then
      File.read('index.html')
      break
    else 
      "you're not authorized"
    end
  end

end
```

If I were to remove the line that says break within the if statement, I get this error:

```
  NoMethodError at /
  undefined method `bytesize' for #<Hash:0x007fcf60970a68>
  file: utils.rb location: bytesize line: 369
```

Comment: You forgot to post the error you're getting.

Comment: What I'm getting is a blank page , I've gotten errors while trying other similar things but for this specifically, my page is blank, and i cant figure out why, if i take out the 'break' I get the error below it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a `for` loop evaluates to `nil` (unless you `break` and supply a value to `break`), so your block is returning `nil`, so there's nothing to render.

But the real problem is that `for` is the wrong solution here. What you're trying to do is check if the Array `DB[:users].all` contains a Hash whose `:name` member equals `user`. You can use a loop for that, but in addition to `for` being rare in idiomatic Ruby code (`Enumerable#each` is preferred) it makes the intent of your code harder to understand. Instead, you could use  [`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) (the Array class includes the methods in the Enumerable module) like so:

```
get '/' do
  username = "john"
  users = DB[:users].all

  matching_user = users.find do |user|
    user[:name] == user
  end

  if matching_user
    return File.read('index.html')
  end

  "you're not authorized"
end
```

...but since you don't actually care about the matching user—you only care if a matching user *exists*—it would be clearer to use [`Enumerable#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F), which just returns `true` or `false`:

```
get '/' do
  username = "john"
  users = DB[:users].all

  if users.any? {|user| user[:name] == user }
    return File.read('index.html')
  end

  "you're not authorized"
end
```

**Edit:** As @user846250 points out, it would be better to let the database do the work of checking if any matching users exist. Something like this:

```
get '/' do
  username = "john"

  if DB[:users].where(:name => username).empty?
    return "you're not authorized"
  end

  File.read('index.html')
end
```

This is preferable because instead of loading all of the records from the database into Ruby (which is what `DB[:users].all` will do)—when you don't actually care about the data in any of them—Sequel will just ask the database if there are any matching records and then return `true` or `false`.

Comment: wow thanks , I didn't know for was rare in ruby, I'm coming from just a bit over basic python.

Comment: And since you're using `Sequel`, you could actually use a more SQL-like query such as `!DB[:users].where(:name => username).empty?` which returns `true` if the user exists and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Good catch, @user846250. I've edited my answer to include information along those lines.